# Extending a single class of a library, without extending all other library classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, jar

Suppose that I have a JAR with two classes, called ClassA and ClassB. These classes implements two Interfaces, called InterfaceA and InterfaceB.

This jar is loaded at runtime using reflection and it should contains the two classes.

Suppose that I need to extend ClassA, adding some functionality to it, but, ClassB will remains intact.

Is there any way to create a second JAR, with the modified ClassA, without duplicating or extending ClassB?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you extend class A, it will not have any impact on class B. It will remain intact only.

Comment: @DarshanMehta is correct, assuming class B isnt derived from class A. In which case class B would change by virtue of having the modified A as its base class. Its also important to note that you cannot use two distinct classes in java which share the same fully qualified name. The class loader will always resolve to the first entry on the class path.

Comment: DarshanMehta and @MarkW, thanks. But, the problem is that the *second jar* will contain only ClassA, the modified one. Only Jar1 or Jar2 is dynamically loaded at a time, so, if I try to use Jar2.ClassB, without extending ClassB on it, a ClassNotFound exception is throw.